# Are WebAssembly globals TLS variables by default?

Tags: webassembly

I am reading this spec: https://github.com/WebAssembly/mutable-global/blob/master/proposals/mutable-global/Overview.md, and it says wasm global provides a similar capability as TLS variables, but the spec itself doesn't imply how the wasm global should be implemented by VMs (especially the TLS part for it), so can I regard that the wasm globals are all TLS variables by default?